# How to get object of related table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My query using DQL is:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(

    'SELECT v, a
    FROM MyBundle:Products v
    JOIN v.category a WITH a.id = :id
    WHERE v.main = 1'
)
->setMaxResults(1)
->setParameters(array('id' => $id));



$result = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

var_dump($result->getCategory()->getId());
```

Please, can sombody explain me, why var_dump returns nothing (white page)? I spent a lot of time of solving this, but i dont uderstand, what is the reason of this behavior.

I know, I can select only id of category table I need hole object of category. Query above is just example, that neither ID is returned.

Or is there another way to get object of related table?

Comment: Show me your error log. Enabled error reporting should solve white page issue ; )

Comment: There is nothing, in the log and error reporting is setted to E_ALL. I dont know, if the reason is that the object is too big. Anyway, it is strange :/

Comment: No var_dump output? Maybe an exception lead your execution elsewhere? Tried setting ini value  error_reporting to true and  turning off output buffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses. I found the problem, which was in my dumps. But only in case, when I dumped big objects as was my entity with relations. Skript stoped on it, or something and never continue. So when I removed these dumps, it works correctly.

Maybe, workable solution, for dumping large objects, could be in Enterx's comment, but I could't try it, becouse my app is on remote server, where I have no access to php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is the entity's name really `Products` and not `Product`?

Second, check that the inverse mapping is set up properly for `category`.

I just tried a simple example with the exact same use case, and it works fine.

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p, c
        FROM TestTestBundle:P p
        JOIN p.children c WITH c.id = :id
        WHERE p.main = 1'
    )
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setParameters(array('id' => $id));

if (null !== $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult()) {
    foreach ($result->getChildren() as $child) {
        var_dump($child->getTitle());
    }
}
```

Do as NHG said and enable error reporting so that we could get a hint of what is wrong.

Here's the ORM mapping for the two entities used.

The Parent

```
class P
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\TestBundle\Entity\C", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
```

The Child

```
class C
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\TestBundle\Entity\P", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;
```